# Where can I find the android’s app code?

Tags: java, android

I want to write something for android , I am new comer for it,I know the java,but I need some example for the android’s app for learn,can you tell me where to find the material?(eg:http://source.android.com/source/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a single go to site for Android sample code and tutorials but I have found there is lots of examples out there.  What I have been doing is Googleing strings like "android theme tutorial" as I need them.  Doing that has so far not failed to find helpful information and examples.  Here are a few recent searches I did an a good example I found for each (this also turns up lots of hits at http://developer.android.com which are excellent):

[android theme tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

[android TabHost tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/)

[android spinner tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/spinner-view-android-beginner-dev.html)

Answer (score 2):

The android sdk site provides some sample code you can work with:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html

Comment: this is where I learned it all

Comment: I know that,but can you tell me another ?I mean not unofficial ,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can browse all Android source code at https://android.googlesource.com. All of the git repositories with the word "apps" each contain the sources for one of the standard apps. For example, [platform/packages/apps/Calculator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calculator) contains the sources for the Calculator app.